# Вывод названия текущего изображения

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
If Img1.Visible then  
  Begin  
    btn1.Caption:='Моє місто';  
    Img1.Visible:=False;   
    Img2.Visible:=True;  
  End  
Else  
  If Img2.Visible Then  
    Begin  
      btn1.Caption:='Портретна фотографія';  
      btn2.Enabled:=True;  
      btn2.Visible:=True;  
      Img2.Visible:=False;  
      Img3.Visible:=True;   
    End  
  Else  
    Begin  
       btn1.Caption:='Художня фотографія';   
      btn2.Enabled:=True;  
      btn2.Visible:=True;  
      Img3.Visible:=False;  
      Img1.Visible:=True;  
    End;  
end;
```

Это код программы, в которой при нажатии кнопки меняются картинки.

Нужно еще сделать так, чтобы название той картинки, которая видима в данный момент, отображалась в `label`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А откуда загружаются картинки или они уже загружены?
Ну как вариант после каждого Begin писать

```
Label1.caption:='Картинка така ето';
```

Но я так понимаю вам не этот вариант нужен, для более развернутого ответа желательно увидеть полный код.

Comment: Картинки загружаю с компьютера, не стандартные.

Comment: Картинки какого типа? var Img1: что здесь?

И куда их выводить, через ShowMessage что ли?

Блин, "мне надо вывести какую-то надпись куда-то, как?"

Comment: По большому счету код весь кривой.
Было бы ясно задание можно было бы написать, более мение красивый рабочий код.
Да и зачем использовать 3 IMAGE если в один момент времени показывается только один.